# How to disable zoom Icons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have two folders Js and zoom_assets .Inside Js I have the file custom.js and inside zoom_assets I have `jquery.smoothZoom.min.js`.

custom.js has the functionality to open an image and `jquery.smoothZoom.min.js` has the zoom functionality.

I need to disable the zoom functionality once the image loads.
How can I do that?

I am thinking to disable the `jquery.smoothZoom.min.js` from custom.js once the image loads.
Is it possible, if yes how, if no how can I disable it?

Comment: Once the image is loaded, you can assign a null to the function that contains zooming code. But who else will zoom that without you ?

Comment: @ sivatumma I dint get the second part of your comment.For me once the image loads after that I want to disable the zoom functionality and once the image quits the zoom button to be active

Answer (score 0):

Okay. You probably need to have a temporary variable which holds image status.

```
var imageLoadStatus = false;

function zoom() {
    if (imageLoadStatus == false) {
        // do zoom code
        imageLoadStatus = true;
    }
}

function imageLoadToggle() {
    if (imageLoadStatus == false) {
        // load Image
        imageLoadStatus = true;
    } else(imageLoadStatus == true) {
        // quit / unload image
        imageLoadStatus = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: mine zoom functionality is present in another folder.

Comment: When you include it in html document, all will be visible to all. Only thing you need to make sure that they get loaded faster so that by the time you access their methods, they are available on client.